# How do I debug this error : app:debugRuntimeClasspath error?

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to run my Android emulator on Android Studio and this is the error that I get but I don't have any errors in my code:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
```

This same error occurs even when I have connected a physical device instead of the virtual one.

Comment: You've only shared one line of the stacktrace. What's the full error? Please update your question to include it.

Comment: I only get that stacktrace on the build output.

Comment: I only get that stacktrace on the build output @aSemy